# How to trigger opening new window when there is specific value in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array that contains differences from another array. Whole script is refreshed every 60sec, and it is checking if there is any change in array on value 10, according to the previous state. If there is, it shows it in array "differences".

```
if (!isInited) {
  ownerNotifyBaseArray = data.map((value) => ({
    id: value[1],
    owner: value[10]
  }));

} else {
  const newOwnerNotifyBaseArray = data.map((value) => ({
    id: value[1],
    owner: value[10]
  }));

  const differences = _.differenceWith(newOwnerNotifyBaseArray, ownerNotifyBaseArray, _.isEqual)

  console.log('ownerNotifyBaseArray', ownerNotifyBaseArray)
  console.log('newOwnerNotifyBaseArray', newOwnerNotifyBaseArray)
  console.log('differences', differences)

  ownerNotifyBaseArray = newOwnerNotifyBaseArray
}
```

Data - array with all data in it.
I am taking only some stuff from it. Unique ID, and value of owner status.
What I am looking for is to open a new window when owner field contains "Yes". New window need to contain a unique ID in id field

```
var myWindow = window.open("", "WarnOwner", "width=400,height=150");
myWindow.document.write("<p>Hey! You have a new warn owner on: TICKET_ID </p>");
```

New window should be only triggered by "Yes" in owner field.

//
Small update but not sure if I am on right track:

```
    Object.defineProperty(differences, "push", {
enumerable: false, // hide from for...in
configurable: false, // prevent further meddling...
writable: false, // see above ^
value: function () {
  for (var i = 0, n = this.length, l = arguments.length; i < l; i++, n++) {
  myWindow(this, n, this[n] = arguments[i]); // assign/raise your event
}
return n;
}
});

/////////////

var myWindow = window.open("", "WarnOwner", "width=400,height=150");
myWindow.document.write("<p>Hey! You have a new warn owner on: XXXXXXX </p>");
```

Comment: so, I am trying to have idea how it should look, so far got this:


  ```if (!windowOwner) windowOwner = differences.map(function (owner = "Yes"){
    return id.name 
    })```

Comment: Updated. I have done some digging and found script, yet don't know how to trigger it when there is specific value in differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That worked for me:

```
var found = differences.find(z => z.owner === 'Yes');
if(found) {
newWindow = window.open("", "WarnOwner", "width=600,height=200");

newWindow.document.write('<p>Hey! You have a new warn owner on: <b>'+(found.id)+'</b> for '+(found.company)+'</p>');
     newWindow.focus()
    //})
    ownerNotifyBaseArray = newOwnerNotifyBaseArray
}


    ownerNotifyBaseArray = newOwnerNotifyBaseArray
}
```